# How do I stop email addresses from being parsed as hyperlinks?

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I've got a list of ships in a spreadsheet, and one of the columns will contain the email address for each ship. However, entering an email address turns it into a hyperlink, while I'd like it all stored as plain text. Is there any way to either prevent that from happening or strip the hyperlink out afterwards?

My current attempt is this little sub:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Intersect(Target, Range("VesselEmails")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Target.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then Target.Hyperlinks.Delete
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

It doesn't do the job, unfortunately. Is there any way I can do to make it work, or a format mask I can apply or something?

EDIT: To clarify, I don't want to switch off email address autoformatting altogether, just in that column.

Comment: ...I just realised something. I've had Design Mode enabled all along. No wonder the triggers didn't activate! Ah well, that facepalm moment led to a much slicker and tidier solution - thanks, @Dawid and @robin!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove hyperlinks in a column with `Columns(1).Hyperlinks.Delete`. Run this line in your on change sub and change the 1 in `Columns(1)` to the column number that has the email data - you can change it to a column letter as well, for example `Columns("E")`.
Hope that will help.

Comment: Yeah, the actual removal code works - it's the trigger that doesn't seem to be triggering. Any idea what could fix that? (I've switched the removal code to your suggestion, by the way - it seems a bit cleaner.) :-)

Comment: Currently using `If Target.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then Worksheets("Vessels").Columns(11).Hyperlinks.Delete`

Comment: You can just run it straight in on change sub, without the `If Target.Hyperlinks.Count > 0 Then` statement, just add a sheet info at front, assuming the email column is on sheet1: `Sheet1.Columns(1).Hyperlinks.Delete` or in your case: `Worksheets("Vessels").Columns(11).Hyperlinks.Delete`

Comment: Are you using a macro to enter the information on that sheet or just adding the data manually?

Comment: It's a pre-populated sheet, but the people I'm building it for might need to add or remove addresses later.

Comment: Also, the idea of not bothering with a conditional trigger is brilliant. Makes it so much easier - thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this as an alternative - it is working for me in Excel 2010:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Target.Column = 5 Then
        Application.AutoFormatAsYouTypeReplaceHyperlinks = False
    Else
        Application.AutoFormatAsYouTypeReplaceHyperlinks = True
    End If

End Sub
```

This makes the behaviour column-specific per your edit to the question. Obviously you can extend the `If Target.Column = 5` code to include more columns depending on your form.

Answer (score 1):

I realize you want to apply this to only one column and this answer does not achieve that. But for the record, here is how to prevent typed text turning into links or email addresses in all workbooks you open with Excel:

File > Options > Proofing > AutoCorrect options > Autoformat as you type > untick Internet and network paths with hyperlinks

[image]

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'd do if I wanted it switched off altogether, but in this case I just don't want links in that particular column. Thanks anyway!